# Quickblox pricing confusion based on plans

Tags: android, ios, quickblox

Want to build demo app in android with p2p video chat; after looking at quickblox plan pricing I realized it is not explained well at all.

My question is if I wanted to have 1:1 live video chatting on my app, the free tier would only allow 20 seconds of video chatting before throttling or cutting off the users?

Can I customize the api to allow direct p2p video connection in conjunction with using their stun/turn servers?

Comment: 20/s means 20 video chats per second (i.e. concurrent video calls). So the limit is rather in terms of infrastructure capacity allocated for you, there is no limit on the length of conversations.

Answer (score 2):

On all QuickBlox plans there is no limit on calls length. You can build a fully functioning POC/demo with instant messaging, calls, videocalls and push notifications starting from a free plan.

Currently the main limits are based on total number of users, to be exact:

Basic (free) - up to 1,000 users

Startup - up to 10,000 users

Growth - up to 50,000 users

You can find more detailed description [here](https://quickblox.com/plans/).